# How to bind decimal type in Cassandra C++ DataStax

Tags: c++, cassandra

I am using DataStax Cassandra driver
I am trying to insert progrmatically rows into cassandra table. 
One of the columns if the table is of decimal type. My query is

insert into thetable (id, price) values (?,?)

I prepare the statement cass_session_prepare, and then i bind
cass_statement_bind_int32_by_name the id.

The issue starts when i try to bind decimal. The prototype of the method is

```
  CassError cass_statement_bind_decimal ( statement, index, varint, varint_size, scale )
```

where varint is pointer to bytes, varint_size number of bytes, and scale is scale.

So, finally my question is how to calculate the content of the byte array i am supposed to pass to the method?
First i naively thought that if I pass just a character representation of number ( "1234.56") it would work. But of course i doesn't work. 
Now I understand that byte array I supposed to pass is something what is called BigInteger in Java. But how to convert string or double to this BigInteger array I don't know. I don't think Cassandra driver API provides anything that can help me with this conversion.
So, if somebody can help me in resolving this issue I would be very grateful

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries out there you can utilize to perform the conversion:

- [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP)](https://gmplib.org/)
- [Multiple Precision Integers and Rationals (MPIR)](http://mpir.org/)
- [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html)
- [OpenSSL BIGNUM](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/bn.html)
- [Other multi-precision libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software)

If you look into the integration tests for the DataStax C/C++ driver, you will find a rudimentary [BigNumber implementation](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/gtests/src/integration/bignumber.hpp) that utilizes the [OpenSSL BIGNUM](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/bn.html) library. This implementation does not perform arithmetic operations, but will allow you to easily convert the byte array (with scale) into a BigNumber for comparison and display.

NOTE: The OpenSSL BIGNUM implementation is known to be slower than many of the other libraries. A more complete implementation can be found in the [DataStax PHP driver GitHub repository](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) which uses the GMP library.

Comment: Thank you Fero! You response is very useful. I will try to implement the solution in my code. Somehow I overlooked the relevant fragment in integration tests of DataStax.